# No such file or directory "ruby/config.h" when trying to compile C++ into Ruby using SWIG

Tags: c++, ruby, windows, swig

I'm trying to get a basic example running using SWIG to convert a C++ file into Ruby. I have Ruby 2.0.0p451 (64 bit version) installed and I've also installed the 64-bit DevKit. I'm running Windows 7 and trying to use swigwin-2.0.12. Finally, I am using the GCC C++ compiler supplied by Mingw-builds for the 64-bit version of Windows.

I have the basic C++ hello world program as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

At the command prompt, I use the command:

```
swig -module -c++ -ruby hello_world.cpp
```

This completes fine and produces a file titled *hello_world_wrap.cxx*. However, when I receive an error when I try to compile the .cxx file using the command:

```
g++ -fPIC -c hello_world_wrap.cxx -IC:\Ruby200-x64\include\ruby-2.0.0
```

The error I am receiving is:

[image: Error from Command Prompt]

All the research I've done has pointed me to an installation of the incorrect DevKit, but I don't think this is my issue. I've made sure to download the 64-bit version of Ruby and the DevKit. I've checked the folder specified in the error, and there is no *config.h* file. I'm not sure why the config.h file does not exist or why *ruby.h* is trying to load it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Check that `C:\Ruby200-x64\include\ruby-2.0.0\ruby\config.h` exists. If not, find it and fix the path.

Update:

Check if there is a ruby.h in the same folder. If there is then just use `-IC:\Ruby200-x64\include\ruby-2.0.0\ruby\x64-mingw` instead. Otherwise try adding a second -I, for this extra path. I agree with you this is a little strange (not so much the former, but definitely if you have to have two -I). The script at https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/RpjuvXpFI30 suggests that this might be normal, I.e. you need one -I for platform-independent headers and one for platform-dependent.

Comment: I've installed Ruby from the installer and noticed that the config.h file isn't located in the "C:\Ruby200-x64\include\ruby-2.0.0\ruby" directory. There is a config.h file in "C:\Ruby200-x64\include\ruby-2.0.0\x64-mingw32\ruby\". However, I don't think it's best to go moving files within the Ruby file structure. I'm confused why Ruby's own ruby.h file can't find the correct config.h file path to begin with.